# Using Update whilst using Select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

my SQL programming is limited which is why im having problem with this probably basic code. I am trying to update a record as im retrieving it, I know I can update it if I split it into two procedures but I would like to update the records that it is retreiving for consistancy sake. Anyway below is the code and hopefully it will show what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Update dbo.ASNs
    Set Sent = 'Yes'
    Where ASNNumber In
(
    Select * From dbo.ASNs
    Where Sent = 'No'
    for xml auto, ELEMENTS, ROOT('ASNs')
)
```

Comment: +1 for using "whilst" in a question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this:

```
UPDATE dbo.ASNs
SET Sent = 'Yes'
OUTPUT inserted.*
WHERE Sent = 'No'
FOR XML auto, ELEMENTS, ROOT('ASNs')
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

the IN clause is wrong, you can´t compare a column with a *.

```
...Where ASNNumber In (Select * From dbo.ASNs...
```

this should be something like:

```
...Where ASNNumber In (Select ASNNumber  From dbo.ASNs ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at using `UPDATE` with an [`OUTPUT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Without any other optimizations:

```
UPDATE  dbo.ASNs
SET     Sent = 'Yes'
FROM    dbo.ASNs
WHERE   ASNNumber IN ( SELECT   ASNNumber
                       FROM     dbo.ASNs
                       WHERE    Sent = 'No'
        FOR     XML AUTO ,
                    ELEMENTS ,
                    ROOT('ASNs') )
```